# SpringBoot project Could not transfer artifact

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

I have created a new SpringBoot 3.1.5 project with SpringInitializer.
When I try to build with Intellij I get the following error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.1.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.1.5/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.5.pom

I am using JDK 17, Maven 3.9.5
I am behind a proxy and I set up the proxy in setting.xml both in m2/ and maven_homedirectory/conf

I verified the connection in Intellij Setting/SystemSetting/HttpProxy for my proxy and it's working

What could be the problem?

Thank you!

I tried to set up the proxy in settings xml, change the pom.xml